# Where are type properties physically stored?

Tags: swift

[docs.swift.org](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Properties.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH14-ID264) has large description of type properties, but no info about how it is stored physically in memory.

It is pretty simple when we're talking about instances, but I just can't find any info about type (static / class) properties.

[image]

Is there any block of memory where metadata about whole type are stored?

Comment: See https://knight.sc/reverse%20engineering/2019/07/17/swift-metadata.html

Comment: @Sulthan thank you very much! Very useful link and it also references to (outdated =() documentation https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/main/docs/ABI/TypeMetadata.rst with all answers that i need :)